# How to tag the items of a list, but not the list itself?

Tags: tagged-pdf, tagpdf

I'd like to tag the elements of a list (label and text) but to make the structure of the tagged PDF behave as if the list itself did not exist.

The concrete use case must work with or without a list environment and also these structure elements are intended to be plugged in as children from other elements elsewhere. So the idea is to abstract the list away, and just tag the contents of interest.

However, I don't seem to be able to untangle the tagging I want to do from the default tagging of the list environment.

A MWE with the situation (including some pseudo code illustrating what I'm trying to achieve):

```tex
\DocumentMetadata
  {
    testphase=phase-III,
    pdfversion=2.0,
    uncompress,
  }

\tagpdfsetup
  {
    add-new-tag = { tag=mynote, role=FENote } ,
    add-new-tag = { tag=mylabel, role=Lbl } ,
  }

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[label1] Text first item
\item[label2] Text second item
\end{description}


% What I'd like to do is something like the following.  Which, of course,
% doesn't work. Consider it as pseudo code...

% \tagstop
% \begin{description}
% \item[
%     \tagstart
%     \tagstructbegin{tag=mynote}
%     \tagstructbegin{tag=mylabel}
%     \tagmcbegin{}
%     label1
%     \tagmcend
%     \tagstructend % mylabel
%     \tagstop
%   ]
%   \tagstart
%   \tagstructbegin{tag=text-unit}
%   \tagstructbegin{tag=text}
%   \tagmcbegin{}
%   Text first item
%   \tagmcend
%   \tagstructend % text-unit
%   \tagstructend % text
%   \tagstructend % mynote
%   \tagstop
% \item[
%     \tagstart
%     \tagstructbegin{tag=mynote}
%     \tagstructbegin{tag=mylabel}
%     \tagmcbegin{}
%     label2
%     \tagmcend
%     \tagstructend % mylabel
%     \tagstop
%   ]
%   \tagstart
%   \tagstructbegin{tag=text-unit}
%   \tagstructbegin{tag=text}
%   \tagmcbegin{}
%   Text second item
%   \tagmcend
%   \tagstructend % text-unit
%   \tagstructend % text
%   \tagstructend % mynote
%   \tagstop
% \end{description}
% \tagstart

\end{document}
```

Is something like this possible at all?

**Edit:** I got a proper working MWE which shows what I'd like to achieve as an end result and how I'd like to go about it. Which could be summarized as a "please let me handle the tagging of this list myself" switch (`\tagtool{list=false}`?). The problem with the MWE in practice is that it relies on `\relax`ing a number of internals from `latex-lab-testphase-block.sty`.

```tex
\DocumentMetadata
  {
    testphase=phase-III,
    pdfversion=2.0,
    uncompress,
  }

\tagpdfsetup
  {
    add-new-tag = { tag=mynote, role=FENote } ,
    add-new-tag = { tag=mylabel, role=Lbl } ,
  }

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{env/description/begin}{
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__block_list_begin: \prg_do_nothing:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__block_list_end: \prg_do_nothing:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__block_list_item_begin: \prg_do_nothing:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__block_list_item_end: \prg_do_nothing:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__kernel_list_label_begin: \prg_do_nothing:
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__kernel_list_label_end: \prg_do_nothing:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\tagtool{para=false}
\item[
    \tagstructbegin{tag=mynote}
    \tagstructbegin{tag=mylabel}
    \tagmcbegin{}
    label1
    \tagmcend
    \tagstructend % mylabel
  ]
  \tagstructbegin{tag=text-unit}
  \tagstructbegin{tag=text}
  \leavevmode
  \tagtool{para=true}
  \tagmcbegin{}
  Text first item
  \tagmcend
  \tagtool{para=false}
  \tagstructend % text-unit
  \tagstructend % text
  \tagstructend % mynote
\item[
    \tagstructbegin{tag=mynote}
    \tagstructbegin{tag=mylabel}
    \tagmcbegin{}
    label2
    \tagmcend
    \tagstructend % mylabel
  ]
  \tagstructbegin{tag=text-unit}
  \tagstructbegin{tag=text}
  \leavevmode
  \tagtool{para=true}
  \tagmcbegin{}
  Text second item

  A paragraph in the second item
  \tagmcend
  \tagtool{para=false}
  \tagstructend % text-unit
  \tagstructend % text
  \tagstructend % mynote
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the part about "without a list environment". Does `\def\LItag{mynote}\def\LBody{Div}\begin{description}[tag-name=Sect]` more or less give the output you expect?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I mean I'm trying for the tagged structure to behave as if the list environment did not exist. Regarding your question, I don't know. I guess I have to understand better how the tagging of lists work. I'll try it anyway.

Comment: my suggestion is not meant as code that you should really use. The \LItag and \LBody commands are temporary but will disappear again when we clean up the code. I only want to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok. The answer to your previous question is, at least as far as the tagged structure appears in ngpdf, it seems more or less what I expect. I don't know what else ends up in the PDF from the list though. As you probably guessed, I'm trying to tag endnotes, which may or may not be in a list environment. And I'm trying for them to behave as footnotes currently do, so to make them children of the mark. Since I don't understand what is being done for tagging the list, I'm trying to circumvent it and do my own thing. ...

Comment: ... But if it is possible to tweak the list tagging to reach an end structure I specify, that would work too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Another detail I just noticed. The MWE uses `description`, but in the real use case environment itself is an user option. I see the `tag-name` is available because `description` is redefined as a xtemplate instance in `latex-lab-testphase-block.sty`, but I cannot expect this to be available in an user specified environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I got a proper MWE now (see edit), which hopefully makes it clearer what I'm trying to achieve and how.